# RemoteHost said: 550 Your HELO string is incorrect in James Apache Server

Tags: james

I'm using James Apache Server to send mails. For Gmail, and other services all mails are delivered successfully. But there is one, which responds:

```
RemoteHost said: 550 Your HELO string is incorrect
```

In smtpserver.xml there is a line:

```
<helloName autodetect="false">myhost.com</helloName>
```

Is there any alternative to tune it up more? Recipient provider asks me for logs where HELO string, which is sent, is displayed in request - where is it logged during delivery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by specifying *helloName* without a dot, just host name, and also changed localhost to real domain name in *domainlist.xml* .